# Add a role to a user during MailChimp subscription

Tags: users, emails

I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in Drupal 7, and I don't really understand the roles behaviors. I arrive in a website which is already done, and I have to add a functionality : a newsletter for another entreprise but on that website.

So I used Mailchimp to create a list, and the subscription is possible on the website.
But I don't really understand how to send a mass contact to these people because they're not put in a specific role.

So my question is, how can I put people who subscribe to this newsletter in a specific role (Which I already created) ?

I'm sorry, maybe this is a bit difficult to understand, and there can be a lot of mistakes in my message because I'm French.

I read some of the answers in that website and I looked for some others on the internet, but really, it's extremly complicated, I don't even know where to put those php codes I found.

Thank you really much for reading it, if you can help me, I would really be pleased !

Comment: Why do you need to assign a role to users who subscribe to the newsletter? When they subscribe, they are added to the list in mailchimp. You can simply send the newsletter to all subscribers of the list through mailchimp's interface without worrying about user roles.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) you can add a condition and put action to it.
condition -> when to activate your rule: when a person subscribes
action-> add user role.
Hope this solves your problem